# How to uninstall Windows versions of Linux Mint, after I refreshed my Windows 8 system?

Tags: windows-8, linux-mint, uninstall

You see, I refreshed my Windows 8 system, and now I've lost the Linux Mint uninstall option, though it's kept Linux Mint's files.

So how can I uninstall Linux Mint? I can't even find the original Windows installer, nor can I even download it from their website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you directly remove the main directory from the hard drive? Or are you worried about the other files it's installed?

Then I would ***Recommend*** EasyBCD to configure your bootloader: http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

**Here's a tutorial aswell :P** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AT2abDMINvU

***Alternatively*** I recommend CCleaner. Turn on system cleanup analyze for unused DLL's. But thats just me.

Comment: I've got EasyBCD - I am worried about the other files though, which is why I'd like an uninstaller.

Comment: @think123  Simple! :D Just goto Windows and **set a restore point** if you don't know howto just google it. It will reset the settings and core files incase of anything bad happens. You could even use the restore point in the Windows Recovery Options at bootup! :D

Comment: well, that's not really what I was aiming for. Isn't there an uninstaller?

Comment: There would have been but the refresh point makes that not possible

Comment: @think123 Sorry for the much later response (internet went out :F) How about going to the windows Program and Features page and uninstalling it from there? Sorry if my knowledge of running linux seems negligible but could you do that? Or try CCleaner, it might help.

Comment: no, it's good. 50 rep in one day - rather impressive for a new user.